# Connect Digital monitor to Arduino?

Tags: programming, web-server, display

I need a small display with ~ 5 digits.
The display needs to show number of visits to my site in real-time.

(Every time someone visits it needs to increase by one).

I thought to create an app, that fetches server stats every 10 seconds, and checks new number of visitors.

Do you think it is better to do with Arduino or Raspberry Pi?

Do you know of a digits monitor that can be connected to it?

Comment: A 7 segment display (they come from tiny to huge) or SPI Character or Graphic display fits with an Arduino.  But once you add networking a pi is a better conceptual fit though has a lot of practical complications.  A simple Android tablet may be considered, too.

Comment: For the complexity of the pulling of the data from a specific API, I would suggest to use i2c screen from adafruit and a python script running on raspberry pi.
this will save you time on coding eth interface and just mostly copy and  paste some simple code to communicate to the display

Comment: @max246 I came in to write pretty much the same thing, so you should post that s an answer

Comment: Trivial edits to a question that isn't specific enough for the site and has been abandoned by its asker are not going to redeem it - they just undeservedly bump it back to the top of the queue.  If the poster won't nail down their requirement, this should be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on how used to you are with using pi or arduino. What you want can be done in both ways.
The displaying of count is common for both. It can be done using a 16X1 LCD display, 5 different 7 segment LED connected via decoders or a graphic display module. Interfacing all these with Arduino will be relatively simpler than Pi.

For the fetching of data and sending it to your device for displaying it. You can use ESP8266 Wi-Fi module with arduino and pull the data. Which is not as simple as it sounds but it is not impossible too.

For pi, (like @max246 said) you can run a python script and use another api to get the data.

Answer (score 1):

For the complexity of the pulling of the data from a specific API, I would suggest to use i2c screen from adafruit and a python script running on raspberry pi. this will save you time on coding eth interface and just mostly copy and paste some simple code to communicate to the display

This is one module that I used and it is simple to use: https://www.adafruit.com/products/1270